# how to get the domain(s) of a 365 tenant if you have the tenant id?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365, office365api

Currently you can get the tenant id for a given domain associated with a 365 tenant by using the GET response of [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{domainname}/.well-known/openid-configuration](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Bdomainname%7D/.well-known/openid-configuration)

However, I haven't been able to find a way to take a given tenant id and get the domain(s) associated with that tenant.  Is there a way to get at least the primary domain for a given tenant?

This is assuming no existing partner/reseller relationship with the given tenant, so AFAICT I can't use the id for managed tenants at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/managedtenants-tenant-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

I've tried [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/.well-known/openid-configuration](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant-id%7D/.well-known/openid-configuration) and that gives a response, but nothing seems to include any of the tenant domains nor does it seem to include any pointers to urls that would return it AFAICT.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/organization-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization
```

It returns tenant id and verified domains

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "id": "<tenant id>",
            "displayName": "Contoso",
            ...
            "verifiedDomains": [
                {
                    "capabilities": "Email, OrgIdAuthentication",
                    "isDefault": false,
                    "isInitial": false,
                    "name": "contoso.eu",
                    "type": "Managed"
                },
                {
                    "capabilities": "Email, OfficeCommunicationsOnline",
                    "isDefault": false,
                    "isInitial": true,
                    "name": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "type": "Managed"
                },
                {
                    "capabilities": "Email, OfficeCommunicationsOnline, OrgIdAuthentication, Yammer",
                    "isDefault": true,
                    "isInitial": false,
                    "name": "contoso.com",
                    "type": "Managed"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Another option is to use [findTenantInformationByTenantId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/tenantrelationship-findtenantinformationbytenantid?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/tenantRelationships/findTenantInformationByTenantId(tenantId='{id}')
```

Response

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.tenantInformation",
    "tenantId": "xxx",
    "federationBrandName": null,
    "displayName": "Edxxx",
    "defaultDomainName": "edxxx"
}
```

Comment: AFAICT that works great for your own organization, but not for some other organization you don't have any relationship with, but have the tenant id for.  It says "Get the properties and relationships of the currently authenticated organization."

Comment: @MicrosoftStackDev Check updated answer, there is another option

Comment: thanks for that edit! unfortunately that call requires permissions to the tenant - even just trying to query the well-known Microsoft tenant id fails with Authorization_RequestDenied in Graph Explorer :(

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/tenantRelationships/findTenantInformationByTenantId(tenantId='72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47')

Comment: @MicrosoftStackDev Yes, you need either tenant admin consent for CrossTenantInformation.ReadBasic.All permission or use [developer tenant](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/dev-program) where you can grant consent by yourself.

Comment: yeah, I'm trying to get the domain from the tenant id without specific tenant permissions, just like I can use https://login.microsoftonline.com/{domainname}/.well-known/openid-configuration to get the tenant id from the domain.

Comment: I have the same need, very frustrating. There's even https://www.whatismytenantid.com/ to go from email domain => tenant ID, but no way to go the opposite direction.

Comment: @JHH You can request this feature at feedback portal, I will definitely vote for it https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ebe2edae-97d1-ec11-a7b5-0022481f3c80

Answer (score 0):

The way I do this is by sending a SOAP envelope to `https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.svc`.

More specifically, I'm sending these headers:

```
"Content-Type:text/xml; charset=utf-8" 
'SOAPAction:"http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover/Autodiscover/GetFederationInformation"'
"User-Agent:AutodiscoverClient"
```

And the body of my request contains the following data (before sending, replace the `<REPLACE ME>` string located in the `<Domain>` property, with the domain of the tenant you're looking for):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:exm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:ext="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <soap:Header>
                <a:Action soap:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover/Autodiscover/GetFederationInformation</a:Action>
                <a:To soap:mustUnderstand="1">https://autodiscover-s.outlook.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.svc</a:To>
                <a:ReplyTo>
                        <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
                </a:ReplyTo>
        </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
                <GetFederationInformationRequestMessage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover">
                        <Request>
                                <Domain><REPLACE ME></Domain>
                        </Request>
                </GetFederationInformationRequestMessage>
        </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

A sample response would be (the domains will be listed in the `<Domains>` property):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover/Autodiscover/GetFederationInformationResponse</a:Action>
        <h:ServerVersionInfo xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <h:MajorVersion>14</h:MajorVersion>
            <h:MinorVersion>19</h:MinorVersion>
            <h:MajorBuildNumber>5532</h:MajorBuildNumber>
            <h:MinorBuildNumber>12</h:MinorBuildNumber>
            <h:Version>Exchange2011</h:Version>
        </h:ServerVersionInfo>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <GetFederationInformationResponseMessage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/2010/Autodiscover">
            <Response xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <ErrorCode>NoError</ErrorCode><ErrorMessage/>
                <ApplicationUri>outlook.com</ApplicationUri>
                <Domains>
                    <Domain><TENANT NAME>.onmicrosoft.com</Domain>
                    <Domain><DOMAIN></Domain>
                    <Domain><TENANT NAME>.mail.onmicrosoft.com</Domain>
                </Domains>
                <TokenIssuers>
                    <TokenIssuer>
                        <Endpoint>https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf</Endpoint>
                        <Uri>urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline</Uri>
                    </TokenIssuer>
                </TokenIssuers>
            </Response>
        </GetFederationInformationResponseMessage>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```